# Flutter : Is there anyway to share a provider among multiple routes other than wrapping a nested navigator with the provider?

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I want to make multiple routes share the same provider but the only way that I figured out is to wrap those routes inside a nested navigator and the provider is at the top of the nested navigator

any other ways to do such thing

Answer (score 3):

It is common practice to put the `Provider` at the very top of the widget tree. For instance, in the [provider example](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example), it sits inside the `runApp()` call.

Comment: Right, but since different routes have different contexts, the new route won't have access to the provider at the root of the original context.

Comment: That's the point of `InheritedWidget` and state management solutions. It searches the tree upward for the data.

Comment: I agree with you , in this case , the provider at the top of the app widgets tree will never be disposed unless the app is closed or gets killed by side swiping but in my case , i need specific provider temporary cause their descendants at some point get would be disposed so their provider gets disposed as well

Answer (score -1):

You can pass what is being shared to the new route and to a new Provider widget which can provide it to that route's widget tree. So, you could have a single instance of a bloc class for example accessible to multiple routes, but still only instantiate that bloc once.

Comment: Do you mean i should pass the provider to be shared as a value to the provider of the new route ?

Comment: Say for example you are using Provider to access a bloc instance, like authBloc. I would add authBloc as a variable to be passed to the constructor of the new page, and have a new provider widget in the new page to re-provide that instance to the new context.